# Sidebar Behaves Differently on Wordpress Archive Pages

Tags: css, wordpress, content-management-system, archive, sidebar

I am stuck on this one...

I have modified the default theme to a design my client came up with. All my modifications seem to be working okay, except the pages selected from the archive dropdown menu. Here's a link to an example page where the problem exists: http://mtrainierphotos.com/blog/?cat=15

Everywhere else the sidebar looks as it should.

Someone told me to look for a missing  tag but I can't track it down.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that using the W3C Validator helps when trying to locate missing tags and may other html errors:
[[Invalid]Markup Validation of  mtrainierphotos.com blog ?cat=15 - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//mtrainierphotos.com/blog/%3Fcat%3D15&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654). Scroll down in the validation report to see line numbers and source code.

Comment: Thank you, but I do use the validator regularly. My problem is that it is saying I am missing some closing tags, but with Wordpress, the header file starts a specific div for content, and usually the footer closes it. For these specific "category" pages to display differntly is a mystery since I am using the same template.

Comment: Compare the page source for the index and for a category page and see what the ddifferences are, and that should point to a problem in a template file.